# Junk values being assigned to CL variables post program call

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I have a number of CL programs which are currently FTP'ing files to a Production server.

we have introduced a new iSeries test server for testing purposes and these programs need to be run from this new server. However, the target FTP address when running from the test server should be different. The files need to be sent to corresponding test servers.

A simple program call has been added for this as below:

```
         PGM        PARM(&FTPERR)                                    

         DCL        VAR(&SUCCES) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(1)                  
         DCL        VAR(&FTPERR) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(1)                  
         DCL        VAR(&TARGIP) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(20) VALUE(' ')      
         DCL        VAR(&ATTEMP) TYPE(*DEC) LEN(2 0) VALUE(0)        

         CALL       PGM(GETFTPRPG) PARM('FTPMRCL' &TARGIP)
```

As can be seen above, the GETFTPRPG program is the newly introduced program call that retrieves the IP address based on the program name and the server where the program is running.

This is working fine however the issue is that the other variables declared in the program (to be specific, the first Decimal variable declared in the program) is getting changed. In the example above, the value of &ATTEMP variable gets changed to 04. Can anyone suggest possible causes?

Comment: I'm just saying y You could've just configured your test system names in the host table entry.  In any language or system you should be using names and not IP.  Time to modernize.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CL passes variables by reference. Make sure `&TARGIP` and it's corresponding parameter are defined the same. It appears that the `GETFTPRPG` is defining the second parameter differently (maybe longer) than your CL program. When the value for `&TARGIP` is changed, past 20 characters, then it is overwriting the value of `&ATTEMP` in memory.